# Conditionally merge dataframes based on multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 2 dataframes, with `df1` containing the coordinates of points and `df2` containing the start and end coordinates of lines. Such as:

`df1`

| point | lon | lat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P01 | 3 | 48 |
| P02 | 9 | 44 |

`df2`

| line | lon.start | lat.start | lon.end | lat.end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| L01 | 3 | 48 | 3 | 49 |

I would like to replace the `line` variable in `df2` with `point.start` and `point.end`, conditionally creating the column `point.start` based on `lon.start` and `lat.start`, and the same for `point.end`. Such that it becomes:

| point.start | point.end | lon.start | lat.start | lon.end | lat.end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P01 | P05 | 3 | 48 | 3 | 49 |

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using merge may help you here.

```
# generate sample data
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['P01', 3, 48], ['P02', 9, 44], ['P03', 3, 49]], columns=('point', 'lon', 'lat'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['L01', 3, 48, 3, 49], ['L02', 4, 48, 4, 49]], columns=('line', 'lon.start', 'lat.start', 'lon.end', 'lat.end'))

# handle start points
dfx = pd.merge(df1.rename(columns={'lon': 'lon.start', 'lat': 'lat.start', 'point': 'point.start'}),
               df2[['line', 'lon.start', 'lat.start']],
               on=['lon.start', 'lat.start'])

# handle end points
dfy = pd.merge(df1.rename(columns={'lon': 'lon.end', 'lat': 'lat.end', 'point': 'point.end'}),
               df2[['line', 'lon.end', 'lat.end']],
               on=['lon.end', 'lat.end'])

# merge both based on lines
df = pd.merge(dfx, dfy, on='line')
```

The provided answer will discard lines which have missing points. If you'd rather keep them and not change the shape of df2, replace the last merge by

```
df = pd.merge(dfx, dfy, on='line', how='outer')
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

```
df3 = df2.drop(columns="line")
for suffix in ("start", "end"):
    df3 = df3.merge(
        df1.rename(columns={col: f"{col}.{suffix}" for col in df1.columns}),
        on=[f"{col}.{suffix}" for col in ("lon", "lat")],
        how="left"
    )
```

If the order of the columns is important then you have reorder them afterwards:

```
df3 = df3[[f"{col}.{suffix}" for col in df1.columns for suffix in ("start", "end")]]
```

Comment: Yup, more elegant to use loops here. Depending on what the behavior on missing points is, it might be useful to keep the line column and the last merge.

Comment: @fiphrelin Yes. It's a bit unclear what kind of behaviour is expected w.r.t. missings, or if they even can occur.